# Quote is not syncing properly using the Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, quote, sync

I'm trying to create the flow like this:
When the opportunity is created, automatically create the quote which is synced to this Opportunity.

I create Quote in the flow, store Quote Id variable, and then in "Update Opportunity SyncedQuoteId" I set Opportunity.SyncedQuoteId to previously created Quote.

When I query with SOQL converted Opportunity, it has properly set mentioned `SyncedQuoteId` field, but it's not syncing. Changing Quote Line Items or Products on Opportunity does not sync.
However, when I click "Start Sync" button on Quote, it says it's already synced (by the way, button should be shown as "Stop sync", but I think flag `IsSyncing` on Quote is set to false).

[image: My flow]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done it strictly using flow, but I think that you may need to separate the syncing part into a separate flow.

Have a look at the article below which helped me achieve your desired outcome using process builder and flows.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000358755&type=1

I also found the following guide useful as it is quite detailed.

https://automationchampion.com/2020/11/24/getting-started-with-lightning-flow-builder-part-22-auto-sync-accepted-quote-with-opportunity/